# VSCODE keeps giving me a syntax error on < or any character in HTML, CSS and Java

Tags: visual-studio-code

Out of the blue my VSCODE is giving me syntax errors on all files (HTML, CSS and Java).  I am getting an error even with .   It is only highlighting the <.
It was fine yesterday.

I tried reinstalling but that didn't work.

Comment: Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) **into your question post**. Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled` command in the command palette)? If not, then do an [extension bisect](//code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to figure out what extension is causing it.

Comment: Version: 1.87.2 (user setup)
Commit: 863d2581ecda6849923a2118d93a088b0745d9d6
Date: 2024-03-08T15:20:17.278Z
Electron: 27.3.2
ElectronBuildId: 26836302
Chromium: 118.0.5993.159
Node.js: 18.17.1
V8: 11.8.172.18-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19045

Comment: When I use the reload with extensions disabled it works fine

Comment: read my comment again. I said if the undesirable behaviour doesn't happen with extensions disabled, do an extension bisect